# Is it possible to have a custom dialog message when asking for notification permissions?

Tags: ios

I would like to customize the following part of the `notification permission` prompt:

> Notifications may include alerts, sounds, and icon badges. These can be configured in Settings.

Is it possible to change this to my own text?

Comment: do you mean out of app, or in app ?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

**Edit: 2023 UPDATE** -
This is now possible via the info.plist file - set your custom text in the `NSUserNotificationsUsageDescription` key.

---

*Previously correct answer below (now, May 2023, outdated)*

You are not able to customize this message. Read [Here](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/interaction/requesting-permission/) for more information.

The recommended way that most apps handle this is by first presenting their own dialog, then show the Apple system dialog.

So when it comes time to ask the user for notification permissions, first you trigger your own custom alert that says something like "Please allow *your-app-name* to send you notifications..." and maybe a brief description of why the user should allow this. With this alert, only add one action to the UIAlertController, I usually just have the action title set to "Ok" and use `.default` as the style. In the completion handler of this "Ok" UIAlertAction that is when you will trigger the Apple system dialogue which presents the generic UIAlertController with the option for the user to either accept or deny permissions for your app to send notifications.

So the flow is something like -> users reaches point in app where they have to decide if they want to accept or deny notifications permissions -> app presents UIAlertController that is essentially just an explanation of why the app wants/needs to send notifications -> once user taps "Ok" then trigger the generic system alert that actually makes the user choose to accept or deny notification permission.

There seems to be some psychological advantage to doing it this way. By sort of forcing the user to tap "ok" to notifications in the first dialogue, it primes them to tap "allow notifications" in the generic Apple dialogue displayed immediately after.

**EDIT Dec 2020** -
Alternatively what I see a lot of apps doing now is offering an "Accept" action and a "Maybe later" action in their custom alert. If the user taps accept, then the app displays the Apple system alert which allows the user to actually Accept/Deny notifications. If the user taps "Maybe later" then the app does NOT display Apple's system dialogue. This way the user never taps DENY on the Apple system dialogue and therefore the app is still allowed to show it in the future without having to make the user manually change the app's notification preferences via the iOS settings app.

**EDIT Mar 2021** - (see @blackjacx comment) Apple has rejected (at least 1) app(s) for using a "priming" dialogue before showing the system alert. So that approach seems like it is no longer allowed.

Comment: Is this still impossible? I mean it's 2020. Thank you in advance.

Comment: as of June 2020, you still may not customize the system alert message

Comment: Regarding the priming dialogs, our app was rejected because we use a priming dialog. Apple scheduled a call with us that we should remove them.

Comment: The Human Interface Guidelines link is outdated.

Comment: @MikeG Is it possible to have a custom dialog message before displaying this native permission modal ?

Answer (score 4):

For anyone who is looking for an updated answer: This is now possible using Xcode 13 (not sure exactly what version introduced it but I was able to see it on Xcode 13.4.1 and not Xcode 13.1) by setting your custom text as the NSUserNotificationsUsageDescription key in info plist file. Unfortunately at the time of writing this, it looks like Apple released this feature with no documentation on it but I can confirm it works on devices with iOS 15.4 and above!

Comment: Other answers are little outdated and this is the correct one in 2022 :) Thank's a lot!

Answer (score 4):

Just to add clarity to Uche Nkadi 's answer, add a "Privacy - User Notifications Usage Description" key in your app's Custom iOS Target Properties. This will change the message on the notification permission alert.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In XCode, you can now click your App name on the left to open it's settings, click on Info, then add a new key called "Privacy - User Notifications Usage Description" -> Then you can set the value to whatever you want that message to say.

Answer (score 0):

No, I'm fairly certain that that part of the message is out of your control.

Comment: is it possible to change the permission dilog box (camera persmission) text to chineese ? how to do it have any idea?

Comment: "Privacy - Camera Usage Description" in plist, and the plist file can be localized.

Comment: This question is not about camera permission

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe you can change the iOS prompt, but should maybe make your own. See the guidelines that Apple has provided:

https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/interaction/requesting-permission/

Not the best resource because it does state that you can change the subtext (this is specifically for location, photos, etc.) but this, and others, have some good practices:

https://blog.clevertap.com/asking-for-ios-push-notification-permissions/

Basically, you should make your own prompt. Be sure to handle the cases where they have either said no, or turned it off in settings and redirect the user to settings, if so.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is system message, you can't change to custom.

Answer (score 0):

> **Displaying Custom Messaging Before the Alert** Ideally, people already know why you’re requesting their permission based on context,
> but if it’s essential to provide additional details, you can display a
> custom message before the alert appears.
>
> Make it clear that opening the system alert is the only action people
> can take in your custom-messaging screen. People can interpret a
> pre-alert message as a delaying tactic, so it’s critical to let them
> quickly dismiss the message and view the system alert. If you display
> a custom screen that precedes a privacy-related permission request, it
> must offer only one action, which must display the system alert. Use a
> word like "Continue" to title the action; don’t use "Allow" or other
> terms that might make people think they’re granting their permission
> or performing other actions within your custom screen.

Guidelines here :
https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/app-architecture/accessing-user-data/