# Apple rejected app asking to provide relevant purpose string Info.plist

Tags: ios, photo-gallery

Apple rejected app as the permission description doesn't seem to be ok.
What exactly the description should be for photo library?

Here is what they said.
**We noticed that your app requests the user’s consent to access their photos but does not clarify the use of the photos in the applicable purpose string.**

What exact description should I write?

Following is my description

[image]

Comment: Just write for whatever purpose you need the photo library access. Describe the user what you want to do with their photo library. You can read about that in the HIG https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/app-architecture/requesting-permission/ 
(Btw i think this is off topic - but maybe this comment helps)

Comment: I've already read those things. It's strange because it's obvious what user is doing. It's uploading profile pic. User clicks up button to upload profile pic. Anyways. I'll add text as I mention below.

Comment: I routinely add three "Privacy" permissions to my apps - one for Camera, two for Photo Library. Never had a problem with these. "Used to capture a new image." "Add edited images to the Photo Library." "Used to select an existing image." (Can you guess which if for the camera?) Direct, to the point, and yes, clearly explains **why**. EDIT: And yes, it may be obvious *to you* what is going on, but it isn't *to me* from your popup.

Comment: This question is off-topic because it is about App Store compliance, not a coding issue. Please see [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic for Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/)? and [Why we're not customer support for \[your favorite company\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/)?

Comment: Maybe help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41353736/is-it-possible-to-have-a-custom-dialog-message-when-asking-for-notification-perm

Comment: dfd, I think Apple could just as easily have flagged yours. They let mine go through many releases and then arbitrarily flagged it.

Answer (score 14):

Just write this:
**This app requires access to the photo library to upload your profile photo.**

You can replace profile with whatever it's for.

Answer (score 12):

With message you can follow this steps:
 1. Open your Info.plist
 2. Find this lines and change your message

```
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string>$(PRODUCT_NAME) would like to use your camera</string>

<key>NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription</key>
<string>$(PRODUCT_NAME) would like to save photos to your photo gallery</string>

<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>$(PRODUCT_NAME) would like access to your photo gallery</string>
```

Comment: My app was refused and those lines were in my info.plist

Comment: You must change "$(PRODUCT_NAME) would like to use your camera" to string which explain why you need this permission.

Answer (score 7):

You need to explain **why** you require access to the users photo library. So something like “*to save illustrations made in the app*”.

Comment: Googled for some ideas, found this. Will this be suffice? ....App would like to access your photo gallery for your profile photo upload. Your photos wont be shared without your permission.

Comment: That would work. Personally, I don’t think you even need the last sentence.

Comment: Yes exactly, I've added only the first sentence.